# Google Maps API - Javascript Filter

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am utilizing the google maps api in an application with polygons to visualize locations. Im trying to allow user to filter an attribute  using a select and update the polygons on change with the filtered output. My filter is returning the correct data but is not updating the polygons.  Am i going about this wrong?

Filter

```
             $('#species_select').change(function(){
              $.get(
                '/species_filter',
                $('#species_select').val(),
                function(data){
                  console.log(data);
                  infoWindow.close();
                  // map.fitBounds(bounds);
                }
              );
            });
```

Polygons

```
            var map;
            var infoWindow;

            // Map Display options
            function initMap() {
              map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 9,
                center: {lat: 42.05, lng: -70.25},
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
              });



            // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon.

            var cc_peaked_hill =  [
              {lat: 42.049803, lng: -69.970551},
              {lat: 42.048273, lng: -69.978790},
              {lat: 42.043684, lng: -70.046082},
              {lat: 42.043684, lng: -70.058441},
              {lat: 42.056940, lng: -70.085907},
              {lat: 42.070194, lng: -70.118179},
              {lat: 42.079369, lng: -70.156631},
              {lat: 42.082426, lng: -70.177231}, 
              {lat: 42.082936, lng: -70.195084}, 
              {lat: 42.084974, lng: -70.210190},
              {lat: 42.089561, lng: -70.210190}, 
              {lat: 42.098732, lng: -70.210190}, 
              {lat: 42.107902, lng: -70.212250},
              {lat: 42.114524, lng: -70.215683}, 
              {lat: 42.115033, lng: -70.188217},
              {lat: 42.115033, lng: -70.162811},
              {lat: 42.110958, lng: -70.127792},
              {lat: 42.103827, lng: -70.090714},
              {lat: 42.088541, lng: -70.046768},
              {lat: 42.074782, lng: -70.011749},
              {lat: 42.049803, lng: -69.970551}
              ]
            ;

            // Construct the polygon.
            var cc_peaked_hill_billsPollygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
              paths: cc_peaked_hill,
              strokeColor: '#F7F8FF',
              strokeOpacity: 0.8,
              strokeWeight: 1,
              fillColor: '#4562A8',
              fillOpacity: 0.45,
              editable: false,  
              map: map
            });

            // Add a listener for the click event.
            cc_peaked_hill_billsPollygon.addListener('click',

            // Set info window content to location report
            function (event) {
              console.log(location_reports);
              var location_reports = cc_peaked_hill;

              var contentString = 
              '<table>\n 
                      <thead>\n   
                      <tr>  \n      
                      <th>Date<\/th>\n      
                      <th>Target Species<\/th>\n      
                      <th>Vessel Name<\/th>\n     
                      <th>Primary Method<\/th>\n      
                      <th>Catch Total<\/th>\n     
                      <th>Trip Summary<\/th>\n    
                      <\/tr>\n  
                      <\/thead>\n\n 
                      <tbody>\n  
                      <b>CC - Peaked Hill<\/b> 
                      <br>\n  Peaked Hill Bar <br> <br>\n    
                      <tr>\n      <td>2016-05-29<\/td>  \n      
                      <td>Tuna<\/td>\n      
                      <td>Endurance<\/td>\n     
                      <td>live bait<\/td>\n     
                      <td>1<\/td>\n     
                      <td>Good bite on outgoing<\/td>\n    
                      <\/tr>\n    
                      <tr>\n      
                      <td>2016-06-01<\/td>  \n      
                      <td>Tuna<\/td>\n      
                      <td>Tradition<\/td>\n     
                      <td>Live Bait<\/td>\n     
                      <td>1<\/td>\n     
                      <td>Kite bite live mack<\/td>\n   
                      <\/tr>\n    <tr>\n      
                      <td>2016-06-07<\/td>  \n      
                      <td>Bluefish<\/td>\n      
                      <td>Obsession<\/td>\n     
                      <td>Live Bait<\/td>\n     
                      <td>1<\/td>\n     
                      <td>Top water bite at daybreak<\/td>\n   
                      <\/tr>\n  
                      <\/tbody>\n
                      <\/table>';            

              // Replace the info window's content and position.
              infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
              infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
              infoWindow.open(map);
              }
            );
```

HTML

```
           <form id="species_form" action="/species_filter" >
                <select name="species" class="form-control m-b" id="species_select">
                    <option value="Tuna">Tuna</option>
                    <option value="Haddock">Haddock</option>
                    <option value="Bass">Bass</option>
                    <option value="Flounder">Flounder</option>
                    <option value="Bluefish">Bluefish</option>
                    <option value="Striped Bass">Striped Bass</option>
                    <option value="Cod & Haddock">Cod</option>
                </select>
            </form>
```

Comment: I would rephrase your question.  It seems to me like what you're really trying to solve is how do you update your map with new data after you have made an ajax call to your own server.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but try to create [`onMapReady()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/OnMapReadyCallback) to [`onConnected()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks), add buildGoogleApiClient() call from `onCreate()` to `onMapReady()`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
//buildGoogleApiClient();

// Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
mMap = googleMap;

mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

//add this here:
buildGoogleApiClient();

//LatLng loc = new LatLng(lat, lng);

//mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(loc));
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
mGoogleApiClient);
if (mLastLocation != null) {
lat = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
lng = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(loc));
}
}
```

You can use [`requestLocationUpdates()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi), and call `removeLocationUpdates()` when the first location comes in.

Here's a demo app which can help you to understand how maps api works: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/tree/master/ApiDemos